# Cambiar cantidad de productos a mostrar en woocomerce

Tags: php, wordpress

¿Cómo se puede modificar la cantidad de productos a mostrar sin que lo herede de la cantidad de post de wordpress?

Por el motivo que sea, quiero tener en mi listado de artículos 4 por página en mi listado de productos 12 por página

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución es simple, en el archivo functions.php hay que añadir la siguiente linea:

```
add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', create_function( '$cols', 'return 12;' ), 20 );
```

Esto es un filtro de woocomerce que se interpondrá entre la llamada del bucle de productos modificando la cantidad de productos a mostrar.